# Using ATTiny85 as a USB HID Mouse

Tags: usb, attiny, mouse

Our project involves using an arduino compatible microcontroller to control a mouse on a computer with an accelerometer and flex sensor. We had narrowed down to the ATTiny85 due to its small size.

We found a particular tutorial on the Adafruit tutorial  [website](https://learn.adafruit.com/pro-trinket-usb-hid-mouse/overview), using the Adafruit Pro Trinket using the same ATTiny85.

Is there a reason to believe that this won't work?

Also, does anyone have suggestions as to which board to use apart from Micro as it isn't too available here?

Answer (score 4):

Due to the lack of USB-Support of the ATtiny85 you will be forced to use something like [V-USB](https://www.obdev.at/products/vusb/index.html) as the tutorial does. This might have implications when you are targeting a commercial product.

Personally I'd suggest using the ATmega32u4. It has USB build right in.

But basically I don't see any reasons why it should not work.

Comment: If we use a breakout board with a USB like

Comment: If we use a breakout board with a USB like this one we won't need V-USB right? https://www.amazon.in/dp/B00Z09R3YC/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apa_i_LKhnyb5J9FFWE

Comment: The description tells so. But it does not state how the USB is addressed. I suspect there is a boot loader that is used for programming (and therefore reduces the available space) basing on V-USB or similar. Perhaps it provides a wrapper so you can address USB easily.

Comment: There is a USB port right?

Answer (score 0):

@Kwasmich raises a good point about the 32u4. Here is a little more information about it.

- Works at 5V and 3.3V
- Compatible with the Arduino IDE
- Built-in USB
- Very close to the ATmega328

Here are a couple of cheap breakouts for it

- Arduino Pro Micro ([5V/16MHz](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12640), [3.3V/8MHz](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12587))
- [Arduino Micro](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardMicro)
- [Dreamer Nano V4](https://www.dfrobot.com/wiki/index.php/Dreamer_Nano_V4.0_(DFR0213))

Comment: You forgot about the [Arduino Leonardo](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardLeonardo)

Comment: @Kwasmich, too big, never seen a mouse that big. I suggested the smallest models.

Comment: @Kwasmich we were aiming to be as portable as possible.